# @Html.Actionlink changing link to controller when adding class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a class to a link in my navbar using @Html.ActionLink.

```
<li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Threaded Styli", "ThreadedM5", "ThreadedStyli", new { @class = "nav-link" }) </li>
```

When I do, the generated link ends up with **/Home/ThreadedM5**.

if I leave the class out like this,

```
<li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Threaded Styli", "ThreadedM5", "ThreadedStyli") </li>
```

The path comes out correctly **/ThreadedStyli/ThreadedM5**

I am trying to use Bootstrap 4.1.0 if that makes a difference.
Is my syntax not right?

Comment: You are using the wrong overload - you need to add a 4th parameter for the route values - `@Html.ActionLink("Threaded Styli", "ThreadedM5", "ThreadedStyli", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })`

Comment: Thanks. I think I have been staring at it too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the overload incorrectly

Use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068(v=vs.118).aspx) of the `ActionLink` helper method.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

The fourth parameter is the route values object and that will be used to generate the querystring items for the anchor tag's `href` attribute value.  If you do not have any, simply pass `null`. The fifth parameter is an object for  `htmlAttributes`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Threaded Styli", "ThreadedM5", "ThreadedStyli",
                                                 null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
```